# Ruby Selenium PageObjects Template

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, selenium, pageobjects

If possible does anyone have a template for setting up selenium tests using a pageObject design pattern.

What i would like to do is create a parent class which opens the browser. I can then pass that browser variable to another subclasses for pages such as LoginPage etc etc.

If anyone could be further information on this that would be great.

My main problem is getting the subclasses to inherit the browser variable.

I would really appreciate some help with this, any answer welcome to help point me in the right direction.

Cheers,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

There is a page objects Gem.  it works with both watir-webdriver and selenium-webdriver.

We had a 4 hour class on using that gem, watir-webdriver and cucumber at the recent test automation bazaar conference.  you can find it [here](https://github.com/watir/watir-bazaar/wiki/Test-Automation-Workshop-2012)

Give it a shot, you can use it with either.. (and you may find you prefer the watir api to what selenium uses (I know I do)  and if you like selenium, well that's an option too since the gem supports both